# Laravel Dusk: Element is not clickable at point (x, y). Other Element would receive the click

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

I am trying to check the checkbox with `laravel Dusk` which contains other clickable links like `Terms of Service` and `Privacy Policy`
[image: Screenshot of the checkbox]

When I try to check this checkbox on my test I get the following error

```
Element is not clickable at point (466, 438). Other element would receive the click: <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">...</label>
```

This is what I am trying to do

```
public function testRegister()
{
    $template = factory(User::class)->make();

    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($template) {
        $browser
            ->visit(new Register)
            ->type('name', $template->name->full)
            ->type('phone', $template->phone)
            ->type('email', strtoupper($template->email))
            ->type('password', 'dummy-pass')
            ->check('agree')
            ->press('Create Account')
            ->assertRouteIs('dashboard')
            ->assertAuthenticated();
    });

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [
        'email' => $template->email,
    ]);
}
```

I have tried to maximize and scroll the browser using

```
$browser->maximize();
$browser->driver->executeScript('window.scrollTo(0, 400);');
```

Apart from using `check` method I tried to use `click` method with button selector as well like

```
$browser->click('input#button-selector');
```

I am not finding the way to solve this issue. Is there any way to fix this issue? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show your HTML code?

Comment: I got it fixed by using the `outer label` selector in `check` method. I will add that to the answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it fixed by using the `outer label` selector instead of checkbox name. For example for my issue this is what i have done with my test case.

```
public function testRegister()
{
    $template = factory(User::class)->make();

    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($template) {
        $browser
            ->visit(new Register)
            ->type('name', $template->name->full)
            ->type('phone', $template->phone)
            ->type('email', strtoupper($template->email))
            ->type('password', 'dummy-pass')
            ->check('@agree')
            ->press('Create Account')
            ->assertRouteIs('dashboard')
            ->assertAuthenticated();
    });

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [
        'email' => $template->email,
    ]);
}
```

And in my `Register` page, i have `agree` selector registered in `elements` method as following

```
public function elements()
{
    return [
        '@agree' => 'label.mt-checkbox',
    ];
}
```

It did solved my issue by using the outer label selector of checkbox. I hope this will help some one in future.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, it didn't work because I had two modal windows with the same elements.